# How to allocate a value to a specific xpath variable?

Tags: python-3.x, xpath

I have a html code, as shown below.

```
<div class="perc">
  <div class="blc-p">
    <span class="green_r " style="width:75%">75,0%</span>
  </div>
  <div class="blc-p">
    <span class="yellow_r small" style="width:14%"></span>
     14,2%
  </div>
  <div class="blc-p">
    <span class="red_r small" style="width:10%"></span> 
     10,8%
  </div>
</div>
```

From the above html, I am getting the xpath for the class="red_r small" which is :

```
red = doc.xpath('.//div[@class="perc"]/div[3]/span[@class="red_r small"]')
```

I am trying to assign a value to 'red' according the position in the the div of class "perc", such that:

if 'red' is in the first div of class "blc-p", the value of red becomes 1. 
 if 'red' is in the second div of class "blc-p", the value of red becomes 'N'.
 if 'red' is in the third div of class "blc-p", the value of red becomes 2.

In the example above, red = 2 because it is in the third div of class "blc-p".

How do I achieve this using xpath and python3?
Thanks

Comment: why can't you simply specify `doc.xpath('.//div[@class="perc"]//span[@class="red_r small"]')`, by that way red will be picked-up irrespective of it's position.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Functions on Sequences https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_functions.asp#sequence

Your solution is something like this, where 3 is the index of the element:

```
index-of(//span, //span[contains(@class, "red")])
```

[image]